# Windows Phone 8.1 Google Book REST Api call with HttpClient: HRESULT: 0x80072EFD

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to write some app that needs to fetch info about books. That's why I am using Google Book Api. The Official library is not working on WP8.1 so I am trying to do everything by myself with the help of the Internet. That is what I wrote:

```
 public async Task<RootObject> GetBooks(string query)
    {

        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

            string requestUri = googleApiUri + "q=" + query.Replace(" ", "+") + "&maxResults=10&orderBy=relevance&printType=books&projection=lite";
            string jsonString = "";
            try
            {
                jsonString = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri(requestUri));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string message = "Error = " + ex.HResult.ToString("X") +
                "  Message: " + ex.Message;
            }

            return ResponseToJson(jsonString);

        }
    }

    private RootObject ResponseToJson(string message)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(message);
    }
```

However, the call httpClient.GetStringAsync is throwing me an error: **"Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EFD"**. I've no idea why's that happening and I can't find anything on the Internet about such exception. Am I doing something wrong with httpClient? I will be very greatful for any help!

Thank You in advance!

BestRegards,
Roman

Comment: That's ERROR_WINHTTP_CANNOT_CONNECT, as basic as it gets.  Check the url.

Comment: It was my first thought, but when i copy that url into browser, it works perfectly fine and returns the json result I need

Comment: What browser?  The one on the phone or your desktop?  It needs to work on the phone.  Or emulator.  If that checks out then you are being blocked by missing permissions.

Comment: It works Ok on both desktop browser and emulator browser. And as for permissions, the Internet capability is checked - in WP8.1 it looks somewhat different from WP8 but still. I've no idea where to look for.

Comment: @Roman Pylypets, did you figure out what was your problem with that ? I'm just facing exactly the same issue and can't fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have suffisent authorization for your app ? Usually, there is a file called WMAppManifest.xml in the Properties of your project. Open it and go to the "Capabilities" tab. Make sure ID_CAP_NETWORKING is checked. This will give your app the authorization to access the Internet.

Comment: Thank You for Your response! However, in WP8.1 Internet capability is checked by default. I don't know if it's important, but I am testing my app from a test class, and it also has the Internet capablity checked.